# How can I do with Views and Drupal 7 what the Views Or module does in Drupal 6?

Tags: views

I'm trying to find a way to do in Drupal 7 what the [Views Or](http://drupal.org/project/views_or) module does in Drupal 6. 
I read that this module (or at least what it does) has been migrated to the core Views 3 module.

How can I do the same thing as on this picture (marked in yellow) within Drupal 7 Views 3?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your views filter area it is possible, Click re arrange if existing filter there, other wise configure it on adding new.

[image]

In the following window you can configure the or or and, between fields and filter group

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as shown above the ViewsOR module's functionality has been PARTIALLY migrated into Views for D7/D8; but sadly, ViewsOR also worked on Contextual Filters and Views in D7/D8 still does not have that ability.