# Exclude exposed filter for one content type in my view

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, javascript

I use leaflet map for displaying markers, like that :

My actual view -  filter criteria :

```
- Content published
AND
- Content - Has taxonomy term AND
- Content - Has taxonomy term AND
AND
Content type = 1 OR
Content type = 2
```

But now, I want display vectors with a third content type. It works without filters (taxonomy), and add all taxonomy terms to my third content, it's an ugly solution.

Do you have a solution ?

edit : drupal doesn't understand this setup 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to make more distinct and/or groups. If using Drupal 7, here is a clear explanation of how to do it (see the accepted answer):
[How can I do with Views and Drupal 7 what the Views Or module does in Drupal 6?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69661/how-can-i-do-with-views-and-drupal-7-what-the-views-or-module-does-in-drupal-6)

If using Drupal 6, the [Views Or](http://drupal.org/project/views_or) module can do the same thing.

If I understand your problem, the solution would be to put the first 2 Content Types in a group with the Taxonomy Term filters, then use a separate OR group for your 3rd Content Type.

Comment: "And/or groups" in "And/or groups", it's possible ? Otherwise, the solution was a cuton SQL Query ?